# how to change route and pass arguments to relay container?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql, relay

I followed the [react-relay-starter-kit](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-starter-kit)  provided by FaceBook to create a simple application with 2 routes.
 
 But now I want to make the component of one route call the other route while  passing a parameter to the fragment of this container.
In other word, I have :

Router config:

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
    new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer(config.gqlUrl, {options...})
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router
        history={hashHistory}
        render={applyRouterMiddleware(useRelay)}
        routes={routes}
        environment={Relay.Store}>

        <Route path="/" component={App}/>
        <Route path="/route1" component={Comp1} />
        <Route path="/route2" component={Comp2} queries={comp2Query}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comp1:

```
export default class Comp1 extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (    
         <div>
           <span onClick={()=>{//go to comp2 with val=1}>1</span>
           <span onClick={()=>{//go to comp2 with val=2}>2</span>
           <span onClick={()=>{//go to comp2 with val=3}>3</span>
         </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comp2:

```
class Comp2 extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (    
         <div>
           {this.props.info.text}
         </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(Comp2, {
    initialVariables: {
        value: //the value set by the Comp1
    },
    fragments: {
        info: (variables) =>{               
            return Relay.QL`
                fragment on News{
                  text    
                }
            `}}
});
```

I couldn't figure out a way to pass the value to the second router.

Answer (score 0):

If you did everything right, your Comp2 should have history in props. 
And you can use it to navigate between your routes

```
this.props.history.pushState('/home', { some: 'state' })
```

The other way to do that is to use context.router. After creating your Comp2 class add

```
Comp2.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

And now

```
this.context.router.push({
  pathname: '/home',
  query: { some: 'query' },
  state: { some: 'state' }
});
```

More info here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it worked for me with this code:
`hashHistory.push({
            pathname: '/home',
            query: { modal: true },
            state: { maValue: true }
        });`

but in `Relay.createContainer` I can't access it, do you know a way to access the passed value to the Relay container ?